# Google authentication modal closes

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine

someone could help me Unity.
I have a use case and it is when I try to enter my game and the Google modal comes out where it requests the email for authentication, if for some reason that modal is closed without selecting the email, my app crashes and closes, does anyone know of a method to call that panel again or the error that comes out, and so suddenly make a function to call that panel, thank you very much for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEUGB.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you trying to open a game that isn't yours ? Please provide the code used for your google modal. Or we won't be able to help you.